# Passing '%?' to script from zsh prompt

Tags: linux, debian, config, zsh, oh-my-zsh

### The issue

I am creating a zsh config.
The config has a theme file that defines a prompt:

```
# File: $ZSH/custom/themes/alex.zsh-theme

blue='#000DFF'
orange='#FFA200'

PROMPT='
%F{cyan}┬─┬─%f\
%F{$blue}[%f%F{$orange}$USER%f%F{$blue}@%f%F{$orange}$HOST%f%F{$blue}]%f\
%F{cyan}:%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}$($ZSH/custom/plugins/short-pwd.py)%f%F{$blue}]%f\
%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}%*%f%F{$blue}]%f\
%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}$($ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py %?)%f%F{$blue}]%f\
%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%f%F{$blue}]%f
%F{cyan}  ╰─> λ '
```

(See line `%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}$($ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py %?)%f%F{$blue}]%f\`, particularly: `$($ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py %?)`)

I am trying to call the script `$ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py`, passing the last exit code as parameter. According to the zsh docs, '%?' should return the last exit code. However, this passes `'%?'` to the script, not the last exit code.

### What I'm currently thinking

I feel like the `%?` isn't resolving to the last exit code because it's inside a `$(...)`, if I remove the `$(...)` it resolves just fine, but I need this value passed to the python script. How do I make zsh resolve `%?` to the exit code and not just `'%?'`?

### What I've already done

I've tried to pass `$?`, but this will not work as other commands have been executed before the call to the `exit-code.py` script.

I've also tried to create a variable before assigning the prompt, so I'd keep the last exit code before executing any other commands (mainly the ones needed to create the prompt), but this exit code is not correct either.

NOTE: To test the exit codes I've created a simple `ex.sh` that just exits with whatever code I pass.

#### More info

The error that is spitted out every time the prompt is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/exit-code.py", line 5, in <module>
    code: int = int(sys.argv[1])
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%?'
```

The python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# File: $ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py

import sys

code: int = int(sys.argv[1])

if (code == 0):
    print("\033[96m{}\033[0m".format("OK. 0"))
elif (code == 127):
    print("\033[95m{}\033[0m".format("UNKNWN. 127"))
else:
    print("\033[91m{}\033[0m".format(f'ERR. {code}'))
```

The actual `~/.zshrc` file:

```
# File: ~/.zshrc

export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
plugins=(git)
ZSH_THEME=alex
# Bunch of aliases...
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

## SOLUTION

Thanks to user [@user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428).

The hook `precmd` executes before the prompt is generated, so I can use this to keep the value of `$?`. This is the new `$ZSH/custom/themes/alex.zsh-theme`:

```
# File: $ZSH/custom/themes/alex.zsh-theme

blue='#000DFF'
orange='#FFA200'

setopt PROMPT_SUBST

function last_exit() {
    local LAST_EXIT_CODE=$?
    local PR='
'
    PR+="%F{cyan}┬─┬─%f"
    PR+="%F{$blue}[%f%F{$orange}$USER%f%F{$blue}@%f%F{$orange}$HOST%f%F{$blue}]%f"
    PR+="%F{cyan}:%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}$($ZSH/custom/plugins/short-pwd.py)%f%F{$blue}]%f"
    PR+="%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}%*%f%F{$blue}]%f"
    PR+="%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}$($ZSH/custom/plugins/exit-code.py $LAST_EXIT_CODE)%f%F{$blue}]%f"
    PR+="%F{cyan}-%f%F{$blue}[%f%F{cyan}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%f%F{$blue}]%f"
    PROMPT="$PR
%F{cyan}  ╰─> λ "
}

typeset -a precmd_functions
precmd_functions+=(last_exit)
```

Comment: The last exit code is `$?`.

Comment: I've already tried `$?`. However, this returns the exit code of some other command that is executed while creating the prompt.

Just to make it clear, this is the succession of events:
1. I execute a command on the shell
2. Some command is executed in order to create the prompt.
3. Here I need the exit status of command 1, but `$?` returns the exit code of command 2.

Comment: `$?` is the exit code of the most recently executed command. If your prompt string contains several commands, it could well be that this is one of the more recent commands. Perhaps in your case, instead of constructing such a complex prompt, you could write a `precmd` hook, which saves all information needed (`$?`) and constructs the prompt string accordingly. However this could clash with _oh-my-zsh_. Why do you need both - _oh-my-zsh_ **and** manually constructing your own prompt?

Comment: This is exactly the issue at hand, the prompt contains several commands so `$?` returns the exit code of a more recent command. By using `precmd` I have managed to fix this issue. I'm kinda new to zsh and _oh-my-zsh_, I have been using fish for the past years so I wanted to use my fish prompt on zsh. I have _oh-my-zsh_ because I use a few plugins for completion and I've seen some of the prompts that ship with _oh-my-zsh_, but none were similar to my fish prompt. I am unsure if there is an easier way to make a custom prompt using _oh-my-zsh_. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have never fiddled with _oh-my-zsh_. I guess since it comes shipped with to so many themes, studying the example could make it feasible to implement your own prompt using the _oh-my_ framework, but I never had the patience to dive into their code.